# When I use generic with spring boot, I got the Bound mismatch error: The type DepartmentService is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics, crud

I'm creating a simple CRUD app using Spring Boot. I used a Generic concept to simplify the code. when I implement a Generic controller with a service I get the following error **"Bound mismatch: The type DepartmentService is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <S extends GenericService<T,K,GenericRepo<T,K>>> of the type GenericController<T,K,S>"**
here I mention the complete code.

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    private int did;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Employee>employees;
    
    public Department() {
        
    }

    public Department(int did, String name, List<Employee> employees) {
        super();
        this.did = did;
        this.name = name;
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public int getDid() {
        return did;
    }

    public void setDid(int did) {
        this.did = did;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

Repo class

```
package com.example.demo.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepo<T,ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

}
```

```
package com.example.demo.repo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Department;

@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepo extends GenericRepo<Department, Integer> {

}
```

Service class

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

import com.example.demo.repo.GenericRepo;

public class GenericService<T,K, R extends GenericRepo<T, K>> {
    @Autowired
    private R repo;
    
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
    
    public T getById(K id) {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    public String add(T t, String msg) {
        repo.save(t);
        return msg + " inserted";
    }
    
    public String update(K id,T t, String msg) {
        if(repo.findById(id).get() == null) {
            return msg + " Not found";
        }
        else {
            repo.save(t);
            return msg + " updated";
        }
    }
    public String delete(K id, String msg) {
        if(repo.findById(id).get() == null) {
            return msg + " Not found";
        }
        else {
            repo.deleteById(id);
            return msg + " deleted";
        }
    }
    
}
```

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.Department;
import com.example.demo.repo.DepartmentRepo;

@Service
public class DepartmentService extends GenericService<Department, Integer,DepartmentRepo> {


}
```

Controller class

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.example.demo.repo.GenericRepo;
import com.example.demo.service.GenericService;

import jakarta.websocket.server.PathParam;

public class GenericController<T,K, S extends GenericService<T,K,GenericRepo<T, K>>> {
    @Autowired
    private S service;
    
    /*public GenericController(GenericService<T, K,R> service) {
        this.service=service;
    }*/
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<T> getAllElements(){
        return service.getAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public T getElement(@PathParam("id") K id) {
        return service.getById(id);
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String addNewElement(T t, String msg) {
        return service.add(t, msg);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Department;
import com.example.demo.repo.GenericRepo;
import com.example.demo.service.DepartmentService;
import com.example.demo.service.GenericService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dept")
public class DepartmentController extends GenericController<Department, Integer, DepartmentService/*Bound mismatch error*/>{
}
```